# How to find the average of user inputs

Tags: c++

so here is my code (stripped of the headers because that is irrerevelant.)

```
int main() {

float program = 0;
float scores = 0;
float test = 0;
float testScores = 0;
float e = 1;
float exam = 0;
float programAverage = 0;

cout << "Enter the number of assignments that were graded: ";
cin >> program;

for (int i = 1; i <= program; i++){
  cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i <<": "; cin >> scores;

}
  cout << "Enter the number of test: ";
  cin >> test;

for (int e = 1; e <= test; e++){
  cout << "Enter the score for test # " << e << ": "; cin >> testScores;
}
  cout << "Enter the final exam score: ";
  cin >> exam;

  programAverage = (scores/program);
  cout << "Program Average: " << programAverage << endl;
}
```

the last part I am having problems because whenever I compile my program the compiler just remembers the last number the user entered and does not average it. How can i get it to add all the user input numbers together and then average?

Comment: hint, create another variable and use it to sum all the `scores` input in the "Enter the score..." loop.

Comment: I am very new to coding could you give me an example or something?

Comment: `float total_of scores = 0;` then inside your loop, after reading `scores`, `total_of_scores += scores;`.  As is, you're continually overwriting previous `scores` and `testScores` with successive values, not having actually used the previous value.  If you needed to keep the scores around so you could calculate say stddev after they're all read, you could `push_back` them to a `vector` then iterate to access them... that would be a good "second stage" for you learning about C++.

Comment: Well computers do exactly what you tell them to, you need to figure out *exactly* how to tell them to add up those numbers. You need to create a new variable and add `scores` to it on every iteration. See my answer.

Comment: also with my hints and google, you could go far. Google "create variable in C++" then google "add to variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() {
float program = 0;
float scores = 0;
float test = 0;
float testScores = 0;
float e = 1;
float exam = 0;
float programAverage = 0;
float scoresSum = 0; // variable that adds up all the input scores

cout << "Enter the number of assignments that were graded: ";
cin >> program;

for (int i = 1; i <= program; i++){
  cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i <<": "; cin >> scores;

  scoresSum += scores; // adds up all the scores
}



  cout << "Enter the number of test: ";
  cin >> test;

for (int e = 1; e <= test; e++){
  cout << "Enter the score for test # " << e << ": "; cin >> testScores;
}
  cout << "Enter the final exam score: ";
  cin >> exam;

  programAverage = (scoresSum/program); // divide the total score out of program number
  cout << "Program Average: " << programAverage << endl;
}
```

So the problem was that you didn't add up the input scores. 
The variable "scores" only has the value of the last input score. 
You have to set up a variable to sum up all the input score so far, such as scoresSum in the code.
And add up the score every time a score is submitted.

You can easily find the difference between your code and mine by looking at the line with comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
float _sum=0;

for (int i = 1; i <= program; i++){

  cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i <<": "; cin >> scores;

_sum+=i;

}

  programAverage = (_sum/program);

  cout << "Program Average: " << programAverage << endl;
```

Comment: @DougT. so did you in the end... though with more explanation.  The question is whether the need is self-evident after he's seen the code.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah because of this loop, `scores` always has the last value entered:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= program; i++){
  cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i <<": "; cin >> scores;
}
```

An average is defined as a **sum** divided by the number of instances. You're not summing, you just keep overwriting "scores" with the last read value when you do `cin >> scores`. So the problem can be restated as "How can I sum all the numbers the user entered in?" Computers do *exactly* what you tell them to, and you need to figure out how to *exactly* tell it to sum all the entered `scores`.

Well how would you do that in real life? You'd keep a running tally of all the scores, maybe by adding them with a calculator. You'd first initialize a count:

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

Then after the line for `cout << "Enter the score..." you add to sum:

```
sum = sum + scores;
```

Or C++ has handy shorthand notation

```
sum += scores
```